# Skew-Symmetric vs Symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, skew-symmetric-matrices

> If $A$ is a symmetric $n × n$ matrix and $B$ is a skew symmetric $n × n$ matrix, which of the following are true?
>
> (a) $ABA$ is symmetric
>
> (b) $ABA$ is skew-symmetric
>
> (c) $AB^2A$ is symmetric
>
> (d) $AB^2A$ is skew-symmetric

I know that b and d holds true.

I am unsure of A and C

However, for a, how does multiplying ABA preserve symmetry, but squaring B preserves symmetry as well?

Comment: Do you know that $(AB)^t=B^tA^t$?

Comment: @Javi right. But I don't understand how the composition of matrices can effect whether or not it is symmetric or skew-symmetric

Comment: I'll post an answer

Comment: @Javi thank you for your clarifications

Comment: @FireMeUP: Use this [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your future posts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the property $(AB)^t=B^tA^t$ to compute the transpose of each matrix and the fact that $A$ is symmetric and $B$ is skew-symmetric. For example, $(ABA)^t=A^tB^tA^t=A(-B)A=-(ABA)$. Then $ABA$ is skew-symmetric (and not symmetric in general).

Comment: how does this change for B^2. Do we have to compute B^2t?

Comment: Yes, but that's just $B^tB^t=(B^t)^2$.

Comment: ahhh I I see. So in the case for B^2. I have that AB^2A is symmetric, but not skew symmetric since using the transpose condition you have give me, we reduce back to (A^T*B*B*A^T) which cannot be negative

Comment: Yeah, that's it :)